# How can I have a list inside and object in JSON?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

I want to have a JSON to know that in the "ClassID":1, "StudentsID":[1,2,3,4] didn't apear at the class, and I was trying to do a query that brings me the "ClassID" and the "StudentsID" but they are all in the same table and I don't know if changing only the query part will bring me what I need. So my table will be like:

```
Table: School
ClassID | StudentsID
1              1          
1              2
2              2
2              3
2              4 
2              5
3              1
3              2
```

So as you see in the "ClassID":1 "StudentsID":[1 and 2]  are missing. The JSON that I need is like this:

```
{"Misses":[{"classID":1,"StudentsMissing":[1,2]},{"classID":2,"StudentsMissing":[2,3,4,5]}]}
```

I've already tryied arraypush, array_merge but since I'm new at PHP I wasn't able to do a JSON like this.

All that I was able to get was this JSON:

```
{"Misses":[{"classID":"1"}]}{"Students":[{"StudentsMissing":"1"}]}
```

The code that I've tryied was this one:

```
<?php
$list = array();
$bd = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","web");
if ($bd) {
    $qry = mysqli_query($bd, "SELECT ClassID FROM School ORDER BY ClassID");
    $qry1 = mysqli_query($bd, "SELECT StudentID FROM School");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($qry) > 0){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object ($qry)){
            $list[] = $row;
        }
        $output = new StdClass();
        $output->ClassID = $list;
        echo json_encode($output);
    }

    $list = array();
    if (mysqli_num_rows($qry1) > 0){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object ($qry1)){
            $list[] = $row;
        }
        $output = new StdClass();
        $output->Students = $list;
        echo json_encode($output);
    }
    else {
        echo "Erro";
    } 
}
else {
    echo "Erro"; 
}
```

And I've got a JSON like this:

```
{"Misses":[{"classID":"1"},{"classID":"2"},{"classID":"3"}]}{"Students":[{"StudentsMissing":"1"},{"StudentsMissing":"2"},{"StudentsMissing":"3"}]}
```

Comment: what is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: Please show the code you have tried! We cannot help/correct if there's nothing to look at.

Comment: I added the code that I've tryied!!! And the JSON that I've got back

Comment: @dexter I've been trying to do a JSON with one list of students that missed a class. The "ClassID" will be the object in the JSON but I have to somehow put a list with all the students that missed that "ClassID" inside this object. But unfortunately I'm new at this and I've been trying the hole week to get this done.

Comment: @Jeff I've added the code that you asked and the JSON that the code generates. Can you help me?

Comment: You might want to learn how JOIN works in SQL queries.

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys for taking a moment to help me! Feel free to give me tips to improve my questions here on Stackoverflow, I'm a hard worker noob!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it with one query, using `GROUP_CONCAT` to combine all the students in the same class.

```
SELECT ClassID, GROUP_CONCAT(StudentID) AS StudentsID
FROM School
GROUP BY ClassID
ORDER BY ClassID
```

`GROUP_CONCAT` creates a comma-separated string, you can use `explode()` in PHP to turn it into an array.

```
$list = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($qry)) {
    $list[] = array('ClassID' => $row['ClassID'], 'StudentsID' => explode(',', $row['StudentsID']);
}
echo json_encode($list);
```

Comment: how can I do this but with pdo?                                                                               
$list = array();
while ($row = $mysqli_fetch_object($qry)) {
    $list[] = array('ClassID' => $row['ClassID'], 'StudentsID' => explode(',', $row['StudentsID']);
}
echo json_encode($list);

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_object($qry)` becomes `$statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`. Otherwise it's the same.